# Symfony+Ajax+WebShop product details

Tags: ajax, symfony, product, webshop

I am starting to make webshop in Symfony and I am making details page using bootstrap modal. How can I make a request and then return the modal with product details after query to database using doctrine in controller?

Comment: 1. send the data using `$.ajax` to the server 2. process the sent data server side and generate an appropriate response e.g: json 3. configure your modal based on the received from the server.

Comment: This is way too broad. Please, narrow it down to a specific error/problem you get.

Comment: Actually I have no idea how to do this in symfony framework. I could easily do this using basic PHP script. In symfony there is a controller-template structure and I want to get the data from the database using doctrine.

Comment: Ok. I solved the problem. I found a tutorial how to do this:

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKKIs0eyv8M